# Running docker on a subdomain of an apache VPS

Tags: proxy, subdomain, httpd, gitlab

I'm running a VPS with Apache and DirectAdmin.
On root level I've running my company website mycompany.com
I was forced to use Apache on the new VPS, because migrating from DirectAdmin to DirectAdmin was the fastest way to go.

So port 80 and 22 are already taken.

As far as I know Nginx and DirectAdmin are not working together.

For my development team I want to setup a Gitlab docker on the subdomain gitlab.mycompany.com

Is that possible without changing to Nginx?
And how do I route all the different ports to the gitlab docker?